# Sendgrid throws "Error while copying content to a stream" on production, but it works fine locally

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, sendgrid

In my application, an HTML file exist in AZURE BLOB. I try to pull the Html file from the blob and the file is sent with sendgrid to given email. The scenario works fine on locally, but sendgrid throws the exception on published code. Have you any idea about this issue?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Hi @tvdias, I use below code block. var client = new SendGridClient(this.configuration.GetSection("SendGridSetting:SendGridKey").Value);  var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(from, tos, subject, string.Empty, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

Comment: It shouldn't be enough for someone to analyze the issue. Can you create a code snippet on git or fiddle in a tool like dotnetfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a known bug in `Sendgrid`. If the html content entered is very big, the correct error message will not be sent. Then this error will show up instead of Unauthorized. When I changed my html into one much smaller, this gave me the correct error.

Read more about the issue [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/648).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer @Joey Chai. I solved my problem. SendGrid keys were wrong in the production environment.